Yom Kippur that falls on Shabbat - Kiddush for the kids?
Specifically regarding a situation where one has young children who eat on Yom Kippur - is it a good idea, an obligation, forbidden, or a variable custom to make a proper Friday night for them, with Kiddush and/or Challa, and/or the usual food?
Please cite sources, and specifics.

Generally when it comes to Chinuch, the approach is "have them do things that they will then do when older." (That may conflict occasionally with "give them a valid mitzvah", e.g. a korban Pesach owned entirely by 11-year-olds is not a valid korban, but we can let it slide as if they do the exact thing two years later, it will be.) So here, I think it's pretty safe to say that the message is: "kids, you are eating because you are not up to fasting; when you get older, hopefully you are up to fasting, but if you have some medical issue and can't, you will do something like this."

At which point it comes down to whether an adult with medical issues makes kiddush. (Essentially -- having the kids make kiddush when an analogous adult wouldn't is like handing the kid a passul lulav on Sukkos.)

A better question might be about Shabbos morning. Friday night the kids can eat with the adults before Yom Kippur and "fast" for a few hours without a problem (except infants, but they aren't up to age of Chinuch so not relevant) but in the morning they need to eat. Kiddush in the morning is various Pesukim followed by the Bracha on the food. Should kids of age of Chinuch (able to say the Brachos) say those Pesukim? Could an adult say the Pesukim for them but not the Brachos?

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact R Akiva Eiger discusses this point IIRC, but don’t forget that on a regular shabbat, if one doesn’t make kiddush at night he does the “Friday night kiddush” on shabbat morning.

This would be forbidden. Healthy adults, even if they don't have to make kiddush, do have to say Shehechiyanu on the holiday and that is supposed to be done on a cup of wine (on other holidays, with kiddush). The Talmud (Eruvin 40b) rejects the suggestion to let children drink the wine for an adult since the children may get used to drinking wine on Yom Kippur and think that is allowed. Accordingly, adults are stuck and recite Shehechiyanu without a cup of wine. We see that we should not teach children to ritually eat specific things on Yom Kippur, even at the expense of doing a mitzva.

+1 ✓ If you or anyone gets a chance to add in certain specifics, such as a bit more background to the discussion surrounding Shehechiyanu's interaction with Yom Kippur, and it's requirements regarding a cup of wine, so the (excellent) punchline at the end, about how it's a "mitzva", is more accessible to more people, it would be appreciated
